# Automapper - Missing foreign table attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I am having trouble in mapping the foreign table attribute in my DTO. I have mapped the *source* table `BOOK` which has navigation property from `AUTHOR` to the *destination* DTO `BookDTO` but when I execute the query I only get records from the `BOOK` table.

Author:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Book:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    // Navigation property
    public Author Author { get; set; }
```

BookDTO:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
```

Mapping:

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<Book, BookDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AuthorName,
                       opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Author.Name)
                       );
```

Query:

```
    var books = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<BookDTO>>(db.Books).ToList().AsQueryable();            
        return books;
```

Query generated:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
    [Extent1].[Year] AS [Year], 
    [Extent1].[Price] AS [Price], 
    [Extent1].[Genre] AS [Genre], 
    [Extent1].[AuthorId] AS [AuthorId]
FROM 
   [dbo].[Books] AS [Extent1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your query only selects data from `Books` table. You should use `Include` function to also load `Author` property:

```
var books = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<BookDTO>>(db.Books.Include(x => x.Author))
                .ToList()
                .AsQueryable();
```

Comment: why is this query not require include?                                                from b in db.Books
                select new BookDTO()
                {
                    Id = b.Id,
                    Title = b.Title,
                    AuthorName = b.Author.Name
                };

Comment: it mean i have to include each navigation property in query by Eager Loading?